# Vagrant+Laravel9+Vue.js3,Nginx setup gone wrong

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I tried to fix the 404 when reloading in vue.js, but I made a mistake edit in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, so I thought I reverted it back.
However, for some reason, the behavior is now strange.

I can display the front page, but for some reason, when I call the DB information from the specified URL (e.g. http://localhost:8081/profiles) on the back end
The response is the welcome page of Nginx.

I think I have completely reverted it back to its original state, but is there something wrong?
I have tried clearing the cache for both Laravel and Nginx.

Current setting

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        listen [::]:8081 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /vagrant/app/shop-web/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name _;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        ## denay access hidden files
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                 deny all;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will fix your error, but this is what I have for my config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

So I am assuming you are missing the `fastcgi_param` stuff in your config